# Anyone know a good way to convert swf files bigger than 1MB? (Google-Swiffy can't)

Tags: google-swiffy

Currently google-swiffy can only convert .swf files under 1MB. The file I have in mind is 3.2MB. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/blvz/swiffy-convert

I am using this with nodeJS. I feel that it's still using online server to convert swf, but it somehow can convert swf file bigger than 1MB. Probably the file size limit is in client side. I am not sure.

There also is a benefit that, by adding some script I can convert tons of swf in one click

PS I feel that if your swf is really too big, the server still block our request

Comment: I didn't download the zip. I install Node.js from Node.js offical website. And then i use command  to download & install that swiffy-convert thing. So you need to open command prompt (or terminal if you are using mac)

 <code>npm install swiffy-convert</code>

and then run that convert script (you also have to run it with command).

Comment: I downloaded node.js and typed <code>npm install swiffy-convert<code> into command prompt and it just told me that the syntax was wrong. Then I tried typing <code>npm install swiffy-convert</code> into node.js and it just said "..."

Answer (score 0):

You must divide big swf to some more swf less then 1 mb each.
Or try optimize your big swf.

Comment: The question I asked was if there was a way to convert files bigger than 1mb, because I already tried optimizing, and I was wondering if there were alternatives to google-swiffy since I don't know how to split it and still have it run as one program.

Comment: I don't know. Usually I prepare big swf before converting. Divide and optimize it. (of course I've got all sources like fla-files)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, if you have the original Flash file used to make the SWF.

Google has a swiffy extension for Flash CS 5 or CS 6 (but not Creative Cloud).

You can get it here: https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/flash-extension

Instead of exporting your FLA as SWF, you use `Commands > Export as HTML5 (Swiffy)`